# How to read /dev/log?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, unix, datagram

I would like to directly access to `syslog` messages from Python by reading `/dev/log`.

My (very limited) understanding is that the correct way is to read from there is to bind a datagram socket.

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind('/dev/log')
sock.listen(1)
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print(data)
```

Apparently `/dev/log` is in use:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readlog.py", line 4, in <module>
    sock.bind('/dev/log')
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

**How should I read `/dev/log` from Python?**

---

EDIT: per @Barmar's comment - only one process can access `/dev/log` so that part is clear, the device must be clean before reading from it. `sudo lsof /dev/log` does not show anything.

<del>[A answer in a Java thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26324355/903011) around this subject mentioned that `syslog` should be shut down before. I also tried that, `lsof | grep "/dev/log"` was empty but I got the error nevertheless.

Isn't it possible to have several processes reading from `/dev/log`?</del>

Comment: No, it's not possible for multiple processes to bind to the same socket, just like multiple processes can't bind to the same TCP or UDP port.

Comment: You can have multiple processes reading from a socket, but they have to inherit it from the process that bound it. And they each get exclusive access to each datagram.

Comment: Use `sudo lsof /dev/log` to see what process has it open.

Comment: /dev/log already exists, so you need to remove it before you call bind()

Comment: @Barmar: I updated my question with your comments

Comment: @nos: isn't `/dev/log` supposed to be always present? It is not created when `syslog` reads from it (in other words, syslog (or rsyslog, or others)) can be disabled at boot and `dev/log` will be there anyway

Comment: @WoJ At https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/blob/1ab0d897a4f3518fc3eaf9192044eca2545c05dd/plugins/imuxsock/imuxsock.c#L483 is the code for rsyslog, it unlinks the socket by default

Comment: @nos: OK understood, thanks. I will try that and post an answer if successful.

Comment: On my embedded device the `/dev/log` is a symlink, so `lsof /dev/log` doesn't show anything. Doing a `lsof` on the original socket file on the other hand shows systemd is bound to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a socket flag to set, in order to prevent this:

`socket.SO_REUSEADDR`

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

This flag tells the kernel to reuse a local socket in TIME_WAIT state, without waiting for its natural timeout to expire.

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html